# How to use properties files placed in linux and use in Java code

Tags: java, linux, maven, properties, pom.xml

I have a java code that has properties file and have logic to use properties file in my java code , but we want that properties file to be placed in Linux path .
Now , as ours is a maven project , i am trying to give complete linux path of the file in my java code , say "/home/raj/config.properties" and its giving null pointer exception. My guess is by default it is looking for config.properties in src/main/resources path .I am tired searching on net and could not find any clue. All examples showed in net are having external resources are placed in same java project , but in this case it is in linux path which is outside the java project , please suggest .

```
  public static  Map<String, String> readPropertyFile(final String 
    propFileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        final Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(propFileName));
    }
    final HashMap<String, String> dbConfigValues = (HashMap<String, String>) 
    DatabaseConnector
                .readPropertyFile(CONFIG_PROPERTIES);
```

Comment: How are you loading the files - what code are you using?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: <resources>
   <!-- <resource> <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory> 
    </resource> -->
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
    <includes>
     <include>log4j.properties</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
  </resources>

Comment: I have pasted the resources section of my pom.xml

Comment: Now i am not getting if there is any option to use the properties file in linux using resources section of pom.xml .

Comment: final HashMap<String, String> dbConfigValues = (HashMap<String, String>) DatabaseConnector
    .readPropertyFile(CONFIG_PROPERTIES);                          -----------------------------------------                                                     public static  Map<String, String> readPropertyFile(final String propFileName)
   throws FileNotFoundException {
  final Properties prop = new Properties();
   prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
     .getResourceAsStream(propFileName));
 }

Comment: I have pasted the java code how i am using the properties file

Comment: Why don't you `edit` your question rather than pasting code in the comments section, which is very hard to read?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the examples there, not in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `load` method to load from either a InputStream or a Reader

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)

```
     FileReader rdr = new FileReader(pathedfilename);
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.load(rdr);
```

to further illustrate

```
    String pathedfilename = "d:/temp/my.properties";
    try {
        FileReader rdr = new FileReader(pathedfilename);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(pathedfilename);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(rdr);
        props.setProperty("key1", "myval");
        props.store(writer, "saved");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**BTW** better to use try-with-resources to ensure that FileWriter is closed

Comment: Issue is , properties file is present in linux path

Comment: I need to use that properties file in my java code and i am using maven project

Comment: That is exactly what my code is doing

Comment: Maven has **nothing** to do with it

Comment: Sure ..let me try in same way and will update in few mins

Comment: It worked as expected with no issues .